# Jquery basic gallery animation

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, image-gallery

Ive made a basic "gallery" which uses the function below to show a larger picture when clicking on thumbnails. I want to make an animation to transition the thumbnail in to the bigger image. for example the thumbnail could slide to the place of the bigger image and spread to it or something along those lines.

```
function Kuvansuurennus(pic)
    {
        document.getElementById("peukalokuva").style.visibility="visible"
        document.getElementById("peukalokuva").src=pic
    }
```

Some style definitions I use

```
.thumb
    {

        height:150px;
        width:200px;
    }
    #peukalokuva
    {
        float:right;
        margin-right:4%;

        width:70%;
        visibility:hidden;
    }
```

And the images I use and the target image for the bigger images

```
<img id="peukalokuva">
    <div>
    <img class="thumb" src="kuva1.jpg" onclick="Kuvansuurennus(this.src)"/>
    <br>
    <img class="thumb" src="kuva2.jpg" onclick="Kuvansuurennus(this.src)"/>
    <br>
    <img class="thumb" src="kuva3.jpg" onclick="Kuvansuurennus(this.src)"/>
    <br>
    <img class="thumb" src="kuva4.jpg" onclick="Kuvansuurennus(this.src)"/>
    <br>
    <img class="thumb" src="kuva5.jpg" onclick="Kuvansuurennus(this.src)"/>
    <br>
    <img class="thumb" src="kuva6.jpg" onclick="Kuvansuurennus(this.src)"/>
    </div>
```

Thats the code, so how should I modify the funktion to get an animated transition from thumbnail to larger image?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could do something with the format of...

```
$('img.thumb').click(function(){
    var source = $(this).attr('src');
    $('#peukalokuva').show().attr('src', source);
});
```

This would mean you wouldn't need click handlers in your html. You would want to reference a larger image though. Possibly in a different folder. source = 'large/' + $(this).attr('src')